# Hibernate DAO errors

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, junit

I was create simple DAO for my project. And when I use it Hibernate can't work normaly. Extracts deleted entities (Entity not exists in DB, but getById method return this entity), don't extract persisted entities (Entity existed in DB, but Hibernate can't extract it)

**Simple JUnit Test**

```
LTUser ashBri = dataGen.getUserAshbringer();
        repo.saveOrUpdate(ashBri); << User saved in DB (Checked in MySQLWorkbanch) try merge, save and persist too.
        LTUser result;
        result = repo.getById(ashBri.getId()); << Sometimes found user but sometimes not.
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(ashBri, result);
        repo.delete(ashBri.getId()); << Remove from DB correctly.
        repo.getById(ashBri.getId()) << NOT NULL, but it not exists in DB
```

**LTUser.class**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "ltuser", 
    indexes={@Index(columnList = "login", name = "userLogin_index")})
public class LTUser implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id = 0L;
@Column(unique=true)
private String login = new String();
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar registrationDate = Calendar.getInstance();
private String password = new String();
private String email  = new String();
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "username_id")
private LTUserName name = new LTUserName();
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private LTUserAgeEnum age = LTUserAgeEnum.ADULT;
private Integer oldGamesCount = 0;
private Integer gamesInPreviousSeason = 0;
private String accessToken = new String();
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private LTUserRoleEnum role = LTUserRoleEnum.UNREGISTRED;
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_attribute", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
@Column(name = "value")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<LTUserAttributeEnum, String> attributes = new HashMap<LTUserAttributeEnum, String>();
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "rank_id")
private LTRank rank = new LTRank();
```

**LTRank.class**

```
 @Entity
    @Cacheable(value=false)
    @Table(name = "ltusername")
    public class LTUserName implements Serializable {
    public enum NameFormat {
        NAME_LASTNAME, LASTNAME_NAME, NAME_MIDDLENAME_LASTNAME, NAME_LOGIN_LASTNAME, ONLY_NAME
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id = 0L;
    private String lastName = new String();
    private String middleName = new String();
    private String name = new String();

    @Entity
    @Cacheable(value=false)
    @Table(name = "ltrank")
    public class LTRank implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id = 0L;
    private int level = 0;
    private String rankName = new String();
    private short gamesCount = 0;
    private short discount = 0;
    private boolean isDefault = Boolean.FALSE;
```

**LTUserName.class**

```
 @Entity
    @Cacheable(value=false)
    @Table(name = "ltusername")
    public class LTUserName implements Serializable {
    public enum NameFormat {
        NAME_LASTNAME, LASTNAME_NAME, NAME_MIDDLENAME_LASTNAME, NAME_LOGIN_LASTNAME, ONLY_NAME
    }

    public static final String ID_PROPERTY = "id";
    public static final String LAST_NAME_PROPERTY = "lastName";
    public static final String MIDDLE_NAME_PROPERTY = "middleName";
    public static final String NAME_PROPERTY = "name";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id = 0L;
    private String lastName = new String();
    private String middleName = new String();
    private String name = new String();

**LTRepository.class**

    public abstract class LTRepository<T> implements LTRepositoryIntf<T> {
    final Class<T> clazz;

    public LTRepository(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void closeSession(Session session){
        session.close();
    }

    public Session openSession(){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        return session;
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        try{
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            delete(id, session);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void delete(Long id, Session session){
        session.clear();
        Object persistentInstance = session.get(clazz, id);
        if (persistentInstance != null) {
            session.delete(persistentInstance);
        }
    }

    public T getById(Object id){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        try{
            return getById(id, session);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public T getById(Object id, Session session){
        return (T) session.get(clazz, (Serializable)id);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public T merge(T obj){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        try{
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            obj = merge(obj, session);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return obj;
    }
    @Deprecated
    public T merge(T obj, Session session){
        if(session == null){
            return merge(obj);
        }
        obj = (T) session.merge(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(T obj){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        try{
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            saveOrUpdate(obj, session);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(T obj, Session session){
        if(session == null){
            saveOrUpdate(obj);
        }
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
    }

    public void update(T obj){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        try{
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            update(obj, session);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void update(T obj, Session session){
        if(session == null){
            update(obj);
        }
        session.update(obj);
    }

    public void save(T obj){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        try{
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            save(obj, session);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void save(T obj, Session session){
        if(session == null){
            save(obj);
        }
        session.update(obj);
    }
    }
```

HibernateUtils.class

```
public class HibernateUtil {
public static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "/properties/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml";
public static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_OS = "/properties/hibernate/hibernateOpenshift.cfg.xml";
public static String SCHEME_NAME = "dlasertag";

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){        
    try {
        if (null != System.getProperty("OPENSHIFT_APP_UUID")) {
            Properties connProperties =  new Properties();
            connProperties.setProperty("connection.url", 
                    String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", 
                            System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"), 
                            System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT"),
                            SCHEME_NAME));
            connProperties.setProperty("connection.username", System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
            connProperties.setProperty("connection.password", System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
            return new Configuration().addProperties(connProperties).configure(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_OS).buildSessionFactory();
        } else {
            return new Configuration().configure(PERSISTENCE_UNIT).buildSessionFactory();
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

}

public static Session openSession(){
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}

public static Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

also you can try

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
```

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property> - helps me.